# Why a led in arduino uno is not toggling and is always in the "on" state?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

An Arduino Uno LED is not toggling and is always in the "on" state, what could be wrong?

#include <avr/io.h>

```
void delay_timer0(){
  
  TCNT0 = 0x00;
  
  TCCR0A = 0x00;
  TCCR0B = 0x01;
  
  while((TIFR0 & 0x01) == 0);
  
  TCCR0A = 0x00;
  TCCR0B = 0x00;
  
  TIFR0 = 0x01;
}
```

This is the infinite loop of toggling under the main method...

```
int main(void){
  
  DDRB = DDRB | (1<<5);  //output pb5
  
  while(1){
    PORTB = PORTB ^ (1<<5); //toggle bit
    delay_timer0();
  }
}
```

Comment: How fast is your clock? It could be it is just toggling too fast.

Comment: I have converted it to 1s also. But the same scenario happens always. I think the error is with the semantic of the delay_timer function. But I couldn't identify. 1s converted delay function as follows.


void delay_timer1(){
  
  TCNT1 = 49910;
  
  TCCR1A = 0x00;
  TCCR1B = 0x05;
  
  while((TIFR1 & 0x01) == 0);
  
  TCCR1A = 0x00;
  TCCR1B = 0x00;
  
  TIFR1 = 0x01;
}

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP answered own question and found error in online sowftware.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is a delay function problem

try

```
#include <util/delay.h>

/* .... */

  while(1){
    PORTB = PORTB ^ (1<<5); //toggle bit
    delay_ms(500);
  }
```

Comment: Of course by giving delay time in main method, its working. The problem is in delay timer function. I cant identify it.

Comment: @SaliyaWickramasinghe do you think tat setting everything to zero will work?

Comment: Did you mean timer0? I have done this to timer1 also to trigger every 1s. But still same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I have worked with tinkercad and in that simulator the timer doesn't work. But I have configured this in real environment and it worked fine.